# How to find $a,m,k$ such that $a^{k}$ mod $m$ is an even number for all values of $k$ in some interval?

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

I was wondering to what extent we can "control" the equation $a^{k}$ mod $m$. Specifically, if we can enforce some divisibility properties. I know that the problem of finding the discrete logarithm is not efficiently solvable, but maybe there is a possible way to solve the following problem:

Is there any fast way to find a combination of numbers $a$, $m$ for a given $n$ such that

> - $a$ is a odd number and
> - $a^{k}$ mod $m$ is an even number for all values $k\in {2,...,n}$

This means that we can go through each $a^{i}$ mod $m$, increment $i$ by $1$ $n-1$ times and get a number that is divisible by $2$, every time. Notice how $a$ and $m$ do not have to be coprime.

By "fast" I mean an efficient algorithm (even randomized) or mathematical formula. Or might there be a reason for why such numbers $a$ and $m$ for arbitrary intervals $n$ cannot exist in the first place?

Also, it would be nice if one could find multiple solutions for the same modulus $m$ and not just one specific solution :)

Comment: You won't find intervals of arbitrary length. Since $a$ is an odd residue $\pmod m$, the modulus must be odd and $a^2/2 < m < a^2$ if $a^2$ is to be an even residue. $a^k$ can only encounter at most $a^2/2$ even residues. It likely won't get nearly so far though; there will be a range of residues where the product with $a$ will be in the range $(q+1)m < (qm+r)a < (q+2)m$, and for moduli close to $a^2$, also between $(q+3)m, (q+4)m$, and so on. That should be about $m/a$ residues, so you're likely to hit one while $k<a$ holds.

Comment: In fact I think I can go further: your *largest* $n$ will appear exactly when $m = a^2-2$. Then, reliably, the even powers of $a$ will be $2,4,8, \cdots$ until the power of $2$ is greater than $a$, after which the chain terminates. For instance, $5^k \pmod{23} = (5,2,10,4,20,8,17)$, and $13^k \pmod{167} =(13,2,26,4,52,8,104,16,41)$. So for a given $a$, we can definitely find a modulus such that $n=2 \lfloor \log_2 a \rfloor +1$. That won't grow very fast: for $a=999, n=19$. But I guess that's an actual answer?

Comment: @EricSnyder That is actually pretty good, thank you so far! Although I do not understand why it does not grow too fast for the odd powers of a? Could you explain that =)
And I wonder if there is a generic way to choose other numbers $a_{2},a_{3},...$ that also do not grow too fast for the same modulus? That would be so cool.

Comment: ahh, now I finally understand. Then we can just do the same for another $a_{i}$, such that the difference $a_{i}^{2}-m$ is 4, 6, 8, ... but we have to possibly keep picking larger values for $a_{i}$ if the modulus stays the same, to do that. Maybe there are some values for which the sequence has smaller values overall than for the difference of 4, 6, 8, ... Can't think of a solution right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I can show as an actual answer that my comment above is the optimal solution, *sometimes*.

First, we start with $a$ odd and an odd modulus $m$ with $(a, m)=1$.

We can show that the circumstances require $m < a^2$ very simply. If $m > a^2$, then $a^2$, which is odd, will be smaller than $m$; hence it will not "tick over" into the next cycle of the modulus, where it can be even. But that would mean we get $n=0$ and we can certainly do better by just letting $a^2 \equiv 2 \pmod m$, which we can get by choosing $m = a^2 - 2$.

**Previous Claim**: For any given $a$, we maximize $n$ when $m = a^2 - 2$.

This claim is untrue, but it seems to be correct around $70\%$ of the time for $a<200$.

Finding consecutive powers of $a$ is equivalent to multiplying by $a$ multiple times--that's why we can have generators of prime modular rings, e.g., $3^i \equiv (3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1) \pmod 7$. If $a^k = r$ is even, then $a^{k+1} = ar \bmod m$ is even iff $2bm < ar < (2b+1)m$ for some integer $b$, including $0$.

Let's assume $a^2 \equiv 2 \pmod m$. We can be certain that $a^{2i} \equiv 2^i \pmod m$, until $2^i > m$. This gives us a sequence of even residues among the *even* powers of $a$. Now consider: if $a > 2$, then $2a < m$. But conveniently, $2a \equiv a^3 \pmod m$. Hence $a^k$ is even for at least $k = (2,3,4)$.

The same equivalencies will hold so long as $2^i < a$. If $a=19$, for example, we can be certain that the first four odd powers, which are equivalent to $2a, 4a, 8a, 16a$, are all less than $m$, and hence will all be even $\pmod{287}$. And in fact we get the sequence $a^k \equiv (17, 2, 34, 4, 68, 8, 136, 16, 272, 32, 257) \pmod{287}$ for $k \in [1,9]$. Note that $32a = 32 \cdot 17 = 544$ is greater than $m$ but not greater than $2m$, and hence has the odd residue $257$. That gives $n=9 = \lfloor \log_2 a \rfloor + 1$.

Now, what if we start with a different even residue, say $a^2 \equiv 4 \pmod m$ (where $m=285$)? Well, in this case it means $a^4 \equiv 16 \pmod m$, and $a^6 \equiv 64$. Here, $64 \cdot 17 = 1088$, and $3m = 855 < 1088 < 1140 = 4m$, so $a^7$ will be odd $(233)$, giving a *much* shorter sequence. The same will be true using $m$ such that $a^2 = 2^i \pmod m$ for $i > 1$.

Even residues that are not powers of $2$ give some hope, but also start to be harder to analyze directly. Let's examine a heuristic, though: when we multiply a residue $r$ by $a$, there is approximately a $\frac12$ chance that $ar$ will be even $($mod $m)$. For example, consider $m=23, a=5$. $ar$ is even if $r \in \{2,4,5,7,9,10,12,15,17,20,22\}$, which has $6$ even and $5$ odd choices. If we pick an even residue at random, there's close to a $\frac12$ chance of $ar$ being even, and about $\frac14$ chance of $a^2r$ being even, and so on. Choosing randomly, $n \sim 2$, the EV of that geometric sequence. There's a small chance we'll do better for a given $a$, but the law of large numbers tells us we have a lot of shots at grabbing a surprising answer, and our number of shots increases as $a$ increases.

---

So it's clear that, given $a$, choosing $m = a^2 - 2$ will *always* give us $n = 2* \lfloor \log_2 a \rfloor + 1$. We'll say that's the easiest solution, but not the best.

For more values of $a$ than I expected--more than half--several other moduli also give the same length. And in many more cases than I expected (around a third up to $199$ but it may increase), a smaller modulus does better; in some cases, *amazingly* better. However, it seems to be fully random what modulus ends up the winner, and whether there is any better $m$ for a given $a$. Consider: $(a,m)=(151,11875)$ gives $24$ terms, much larger than the $15$ we get with $m = a^2 - 2 = 22799$. But while $153$ also has a better value of $m$, only those two have a better solution in the odd numbers from $145$ to $169$.

Unfortunately, *finding* these exceptions feels likely to be as hard as the discrete logarithm problem. Alas!

Comment: Cool analysis. Does that mean that we have a chance, heuristically, at finding about $n$ odd values such that each of them has a chain of $\geq n$ even powers mod $m$ for the same modulus $m$? Not considering the amount of time we would need in order to find them.

Comment: @questionmaster Heuristically... maybe so? It feels like the probability would tend toward zero, though--going into the $300$s, you start getting moduli above $10^5$, but computationally any given $a$ only had one or two moduli that gave a solution, and the distribution seemed random. So your chances are incredibly small, but the law of large numbers says "Maybe, but good luck finding it."